# Error in Installation of Phusion Passenger for Puppet

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, puppet

I am configuring the Puppet-master version (3.7.3) on RHEL6.3 x64, where in one step I need to install Phusion Passenger.

```
(ref: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html)
```

But during

step of "gem install rack passenger" I'm facing below problem:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I searched a lot in Google and everywhere it was said that zlib library needed to be reinstalled. I reinstalled thousand times but no luck.

Then I thought I should install passenger directly from the official repo mentioned in below link:

```
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html
```

But during step of `yum install mod_passenger` I am facing below issue:

```
---> Package rubygem-daemon_controller.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-passenger-native-libs.x86_64 1:3.0.19-1.el6_1.8.7.352 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby = 1.8.7.352 for package: 1:rubygem-passenger-native-libs-3.0.19-1.el6_1.8.7.352.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:rubygem-passenger-native-libs-3.0.19-1.el6_1.8.7.352.x86_64 (passenger)
           Requires: ruby = 1.8.7.352
           Installed: ruby-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.x86_64 (@rhel-6-server-rpms)
               ruby = 1.8.7.374-3.el6_6
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.299-4.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.299-4.el6
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.299-5.el6_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.299-5.el6_0.1
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.299-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.299-7.el6
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.299-7.el6_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.299-7.el6_1.1
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.352-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.352-3.el6
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.352-4.el6_2.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           ruby = 1.8.7.352-4.el6_2
       Available: ruby-1.8.7.352-7.el6_2.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
```

There were couple of dependencies such as rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.1 and libev.so.4()(64bit) as well, which I googled and installed using single RPMs.

Now, I am out of idea how to resolve this. Any suggestions would be really helpful here.

Puppet -V : 3.7.3

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405)

Gem --Version: 2.4.4

RHEL 6.3 x64

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid this is off topic. Please refer to ServerFault if this is a professional assignment, or SuperUser if not.

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No I could never solve this issue. :(

Comment: you need to install some library, http://www.olindata.com/blog/2014/09/setup-puppet-master-passenger-and-apache-centos